# Bash script -- store `curl` output in variable, then format against string in variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, curl

I was hoping to `curl` data into a shell script variable, then use `cat` or `awk` to operate on that variable as if it was a file.

Is this possible, or is there a workaround? Do I have to save the `curl` command into a file?

Do I have to run `curl` several times, for each bit of string formatting I want to do?

I am `curl`ing ipinfo.io, and want to output the matching lines for "city" and "region". I know how to use `awk` and `sed` to format the output as desired.

Try for example, `curl ipinfo.io/"8.8.8.8"` for the result for a Google DNS IP address.

I'd like to print just "Mountain View" and "California," preferably on the same line, with some common formatting, like "Mountain View, California".

Comment: Whats your input and desired output?

Comment: You can, but there's no point in storing `curl`'s output (unless you want to use it multiple times), you can directly feed it to `cat` or `awk`. As heemayl said please explain exactly what you want to do.

Comment: i am curling ipinfo.io, and want to echo the matching lines for city and region. I know how to use `awk` and `sed` to format the output as desired. Try for example, `curl ipinfo.io/"8.8.8.8"` for the result for a google dns ip address

Comment: What do you want to print exactly? The whole line as in the output or only "Mountain View" and "California"?

Comment: just "Mountain View" and "California," preferably on the same line, with some common formatting, like you know, "Mountain View, California"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general there are more appropriate ways of parsing JSON objects, but since in this case the JSON object is very simple you may store `curl`'s output in a variable (which is possible) and just use AWK:

```bsh
var="$(curl ipinfo.io/"8.8.8.8" 2>/dev/null)"
<<<"$var" awk -F'"' '$2=="city"{printf("%s, ", $4)}$2=="region"{print $4}'
```

```bsh
% var="$(curl ipinfo.io/"8.8.8.8" 2>/dev/null)"
% <<<"$var" awk -F'"' '$2=="city"{printf("%s, ", $4)}$2=="region"{print $4}'
Mountain View, California
```

However unless you want to use `curl`'s output multiple times you may just use a pipe:

```bsh
curl ipinfo.io/"8.8.8.8" 2>/dev/null | awk -F'"' '$2=="city"{printf("%s, ", $4)}$2=="region"{print $4}'
```

```bsh
curl ipinfo.io/"8.8.8.8" 2>/dev/null | awk -F'"' '$2=="city"{printf("%s, ", $4)}$2=="region"{print $4}'
Mountain View, California
```

---

`<<<` is a form of input redirection called "here string"; it redirects the STDIN of a command from the terminal to a string.

What happens here is that `$var` is expanded between the double quotes; the STDIN of the AWK command is redirected from the terminal to the expanded string and AWK consequently reads the string as its input file.

Comment: can you explain the `<<<` part a bit more? edit: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign#Triple_less-than_sign) I take it?

Comment: @cfye14 I added an explanation for the `<<<` token: one thing, note that I asked all those informations to be extremely sure of the scope of your question (to avoid anyone giving potentially unuseful answers); I understand that the processing itself was probably not necessary. janos' answer below is just as much as valid.

Answer (score 6):

> I was hoping to curl data into a shell script variable, then use cat or awk to operate on that variable as if it were a file. Is this possible, or is there a workaround?

Sure you can. If the content is not too large, and if you want to run multiple commands to parse the content, then it's a good thing to cache it in memory rather than re-download every time.

To store the result of `curl` in a variable:

```
ipinfo=$(curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8)
```

To run commands on it:

```
<<< "$ipinfo" awk ...
<<< "$ipinfo" sed ...
```

The double-quotes no `"$ipinfo" are important to preserve all the whitespace characters.

A "workaround" to not saving the content in a variable is to figure out a way to process the content in a single pipeline, like [@kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos) did.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy and more readable way to do this, you can use `python`, which exists in all linux based systems, to parse the json for you

Simply, Import `json` and `sys` packages to load the `json` object, then print from the `result` object any property you need:

```
curl ipinfo.io/"8.8.8.8" 2>/dev/null | 
  python -c 'import  json,sys; 
             result=json.load(sys.stdin); 
             print(result["'city'"] + ", " + result["'region'"])';
```

I added the script in a more readable way however you should put in one line or add `\` by the end of each line if you need to write it in multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Since the output of `curl` will be JSON the appropriate/simpler tool seems to be [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor):

```sh
$ curl ipinfo.io/"1.1.1.1" 2>/dev/null | jq --raw-output '"\(.city), \(.region)"'
White Hall, Alabama
```